# Locate a component in React project

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a Logout button component in my React app for which I wish to locate at the top right corner of the screen.

```
render() {
   <LogoutButtonComponent height: , backgroudColor: />
}
```

It wouldn't let me assign any values for height and etc.

This is the Logout component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class LogOutButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onLogout();
  };

  render() {
    return <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Logout</button>;
  }
}
```

Should I locate it by < col /> ?

Comment: If you want to add style, you should add as follows. `style={{ height: 100 }}`

Comment: that way works @doniyor2109 but I don't think the I.zv should do it that way. I think the owner of the question wants to actually style the contents of the component. You don't really want to add styling to the entire component like that

Comment: to the owner of the question. if you can post a screenshot of what you want it to look like I think we can help you a little bit more...

Answer (score 0):

To add inline styles, you should defined a `style` object as prop, and pass it values, like [doniyor2109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5840927/doniyor2109) mentioned. There are a few caveats to using this, however.

`style={{ height: 100, height: '100px', height: '100%', minHeight: '100px'}}`.

- Not every value should be passed as integer, some need to be passed as a string
- Not every css attribute gets passed as you would expect them to, the css `min-height` actually gets passed as `minHeight`, so replace all hyphens with lower camel case style
- Inline styles get insanely difficult to manage. I suggest you at the very least create an object outside the component, and pass it in like:

`const DivStyle = { minHeight: '100px' }`

and then:

`<LogoutButtonComponent style={DivStyle} />`

- You can prefix that `DivStyle` with an `export` if you want to `import {DivStyle} from './somefile'` in other places
- I suggest you check out a library like [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) as it makes styling much easier!
- I suggest you check out [this article](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822) which outlines your options

Answer (score 0):

You don't really add styles to your component like that. It's better to add those styles in the source for the actual component. So how exactly do you want it displayed? I will provide a template kind of and you can change it to what you want.

Go to your source for your Logout Button Component. In the return of your render method try adding a `div` call it container. Then add styling in a css file to that `div` or if you are using `react-bootstrap` or `reactstrap` or `@material/ui/core` you can adjust the style according to their documentation.

You can add your `css` for the `className` `.container` to make it appear the way you would like.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class LogOutButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onLogout();
  };

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="container">
         {* notice the className here *}
         <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Logout</button>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.